# Falling in endless loop while putting new object in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote some code, which reads a text file line by line in a for loop; Each line is a command for drawing a new shape on JPanel.
I have a HashMap for storing names and shapes.

```
Map<String, GeoShape> geoObj = new HashMap<String, GeoShape>();
```

Sample input is this:
ADD P1 Point Blue 50 50 10

cmd is a String[] which holds splitted input command.
and the problem is here:

```
if (cmd[2].equalsIgnoreCase("Point")) 
    geoObj.put(cmd[1], new Point(cmd, graph));
```

it falls in an endless loop. I ran the code in debug mode, nothing's wrong with class Point.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: this is Class Point

```
public class Point extends Segment {
    private Line2D point;
    private Stroke thickness;
    private Color fColor;
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(String[] cmd, Graphics2D graph) {
        System.out.println("point");
        x = Double.parseDouble(cmd[4]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(cmd[5]);
        try {
            fColor = setColor(cmd[3]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        thickness = new BasicStroke(Integer.parseInt(cmd[6]));

        paint(graph);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D graph) {
        point = new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y);

        graph.setStroke(thickness);
        graph.setColor(fColor);
        graph.draw(point);
    }
}
```

the for loop:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

int linesNum = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
String line = br.readLine();
for (int i = 1; i <= linesNum; i++) {
     while (line != null) {
        cmd = line.split(" ");
        if (cmd[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) {
        if (cmd[2].equalsIgnoreCase("Point")) 
        geoObj.put(cmd[1], new Point(cmd, graph));
            // some else if with the same structure for other shapes
//at the end of for loop I have this:  line = br.readLine();
```

Comment: There's no helping this question.  you've provided no data that could give anyone a clue.  If you are running in debug mode you should have all the info you need.  There's something wrong with Point or some other class you wrote.  There's nothing wrong with Map or HashMap.  My guess is a bad Point constructor.

Comment: Check the for loop , what is the break condition ?

Comment: `readLine()` should return null at the end of stream. Either readline is not called at each iteration, or the stream never ends. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that a single call to `put` results in an endless loop?

That is possible in theory, but only if the `HashMap` is updated by another thread without proper synchronization.  (You would need to do a detailed analysis of the `HashMap` class to determine if this is actually possible / likely, but if two threads are reading and writing a `HashMap` simultaneously without proper synchronization, then the hash chains could get corrupted, leading to an infinite loop when the `get` call tries to search a corrupted chain.)

If that's not the problem, then the problem is in code that you haven't shown us.